# Which is the best way to do database search on mean stack

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb

I am using mongodb to store items for an auction  site
I want to enable fuzzy searching.

Should I query for 1000 results with no parameters  then use a js library  like fuse.js

Or should I rely on mongodb  $regex  alone to do the query?

Answer (score 0):

mongodb isn't a great choice for a problem like this. There are lots of great text search utilities available, the most prominent these days being elasticsearch.  You'd continue to store your data in mongodb, but you'd keep an elasticsearch instance synced to the mongodb database and perform your searches against elasticsearch. Mongoosastic is a good way to write to both concurrently or Transporter can be used shift the synchronization away from your database persistence flow.

Mongoosastic example: 
https://blog.cloudboost.io/sync-mongo-with-elastic-and-save-months-of-development-time-and-cost-d281e0ca8fe4

Some other ways to sync including Transporter: https://code.likeagirl.io/5-different-ways-to-synchronize-data-from-mongodb-to-elasticsearch-d8456b83d44f